# Connection between Vedas, Upanishads and Puranas

Tags: vedas, puranas, upanishads

Is there any connection between Vedas, Upanishads and Puranas? If there is a connection, any citation from scriptures of yesteryear's between the three?

Comment: What type of connection you're looking for? The connection between Vedas and Upanishads are discussed in couple of posts. (Upanishads are ending/conclusive part of Vedas dealing with spiritual knowledge and also known as Vedanta).

Comment: The Upanishads are part of the Vedas. Vyasa is the one that extracted them out of the various Vedas and put them into separate books known as the Upanishads. They still form part of the original vedas they came from. You might like to read here  - https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey

Comment: @Pandya As you mentioned couple of posts for Upanishads and Vedas were discussed. Puranas not discussed with the other two. My question is if there is any interlinking between the three.

Comment: Puranas are the dramatic representation of scriptures. Upanishads are more toward learning about Brahman, part of the Vedas.

Comment: What do you mean by interlinking could you clarify? Puranas are a sub-limb of the Vedas if this is something you’re for?